# Extending ASP.NET textbox to width of row - bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm using ASP.NET for the first time and am admittedly already pretty inexperienced at HTML. I'm using bootstrap grid and I have a form I'm creating that has this pattern:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row dataPanel">

        <h4><b>1.First question goes here</b></h4>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="q1Score" CssClass="radioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">N/A</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <br />
            Comments:
            <asp:TextBox ID="q1CommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="commentBox" runat="server" />

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My custom css looks like this:

```
.radioButtonList label {
width: 25px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 2px;
display: compact;
font-size: 10pt;
text-align: center;
}


.commentBox {
border-style: solid;
border-color: dimgray;
width: 100%;
height:50%;
}

.dataPanel {
border: solid;
border-radius: 4px;
border-width: 1.5px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

No matter if I enclose the comment box in a div with style col-12-lg or row, I can't get the darn thing to extend the width of the row. In bootstrap this means the equivalent of 12 columns, correct?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work with `width: 100% !important;`? Note that a Multiline TextBox becomes a TextArea in html, maybe that has it's own CSS somewhere.

Comment: Nope, !important tag doesn't do anything. You are definitely right that it gets rendered into a TextArea, but my commentBox css class should apply to both text areas and text boxes. I removed the Multiline parameter to turn it into a one line text box, but it was still the same width.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD, looking at the textarea class in my style sheet showed a width limit set at 280px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to TidyDev and VDWWD for leading me in the right direction. When I build the page and inspect the textarea element, there was a style class showing for textarea:

```
input, select, textarea {
     max-width: 280px;
}
```

This class was limiting my text to a set width. It does not exist in my boostrap style sheet (or any others attached to the project), so i'm not sure where it's coming from. I added this class to my custom style sheet and adjusted the width - PROBLEM SOLVED.

Answer (score 1):

An ASP textbox essentially creates a HTML input box. These are inline elements which means you'll need to set the width to 100% of you want it to use the entire width of it's container.

```
#q1CommentBox{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already added my custom css class: commentBox as a CssClass parameter to the <asp:textbox/>. If you see the commentBox class above, you should see width: 100%. Nevertheless, I removed the textbox's CssClass parameter and added your suggestion to my css. This resulted in an even shorter textbox.

Comment: It's hard to tell without context of what the surrounding CSS looks like, but col-lg-12 does include a little padding but it's not enough to usually make a difference. I'd usually inspect the element in chrome and see which of my css rules are having an effect and work backwards from there.

Comment: TidyDev, that was the right place to look. Found a line of css that is limiting text area width to 280px. Problem solved!